# How to compute contour for a triangular grid with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a set of x, y, z data but with a constraint on x and y such as y < x :
[image]

I would like to draw contours of these data on an 2D plot. I first interpolated the data with the `scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline` class and then I drew contours. But in order to do that, I defined a rectangular grid from the range of x and y and I used that grid for the interpolation and the contours plot. How can I avoid to use a rectangular grid ? Does it exist an equivalent of `scipy.meshgrid` function for a triangular grid which can be used to plot contours ?

At the end I obtain the following plot. I added a filled triangle to hide the not relevant data.

[image]

But if you look at the result of the interpolation, the splines diverge where there is no data. It is not a problem as I do not use it but I would prefer to use a grid corresponding to the constraint on x and y :

[image]